# How to get rounded image tag on top of two div in react native?

Tags: css, react-native

I want to create a profile page where rounded image will be on top of two div in 30:70 ratio where top div will be empty and bottom div will contain few items. I have tried few code snippets from web.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: 'green', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: "flex-start", alignItems: "flex-start", alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>
            {/* <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-start', margin: 1 }}> */}
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 10, flexDirection: 'column', height: "30%", width: "100%" }}></View>
            {/* </View> */}
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start', alignSelf: 'flex-start', margin: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 10, flexDirection: 'column', height: "70%", width: "100%" }}></View>
            </View>
        </View>

        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', position: 'absolute' }}>
            <View style={{
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                borderRadius: 10, height: 100, width: 100, borderRadius: 100 / 2
            }}></View>
        </View>
    </View>
```

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miwT1.png)

Comment: We're going to need the **output HTML & CSS** - not your react code. Ideally in a Stack Snippet.

Comment: Is it for React Native or web?

Comment: @ash Check my response to see if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking as reference the image you share with us... You can have two views and set the profile avatar style to:

```js
{
  position: 'absolute',
  alignSelf: 'center',
  etc..
}
```

Check a quick demo: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/avatar-example

[image]

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons, FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { avatar, background } from './data';

export default class App extends Component {
  renderRow({ action, icon, fontAwesome = false }) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.actionRow}>
        {fontAwesome 
          ? <FontAwesome name={icon} size={25} /> 
          : <Ionicons name={icon} size={32} />}
        <Text style={styles.text}>{action}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={background} style={styles.background}>
          <Image source={avatar} style={styles.avatar} />
        </ImageBackground>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          {this.renderRow({ action: 'Scanner', icon: 'ios-camera' })}
          {this.renderRow({
            action: 'Profile',
            icon: 'user-circle-o',
            fontAwesome: true,
          })}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**You styles:**

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  background: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 130,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 80,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: '50%',
    borderWidth: 0.7,
    borderColor: 'black',
    position: 'absolute',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 80,
  },
  actionRow: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '50',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  text: {
    marginLeft: 15,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
});
```